# Cannot restart container OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec:: permission denied: unknown

Tags: docker

Executing `docker-compose up` from Ubuntu 18 installed on Windows.

It's returning an error

```
ERROR: for image Cannot start service python: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "./start.sh":
permission denied: unknown
```

The Dockerfile is just

```
FROM scratch
ADD ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /

COPY start.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something inside the host Ubuntu machine went awry (possible because the docker-compose.yml was mounting that file in the container, but the local file did not have +x permission).. had to do the following inside the host Ubuntu machine (**not** in docker build)

```
$ chmod +x start.sh
```

Rebuilt the images with no cache and started everything up again and it worked

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
$ docker-compose up
```

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! was starting to pull my hair on this.

Comment: What a strange issue - but this fixed it, thank you!

I noticed this only seemed to happen when running with `docker-compose up` not with plain `docker run` commands.

Seems like when using docker-compose some process on the host machine needs to execute the file as well

Comment: In my case, this was happening (and this answer solved it) because my docker-compose.yml was mounting that file in the container, but the local file did not have +x permission